# Proving that similarity transformation of state-space preserves the Euclidean norm

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems, control-theory, linear-control

I am aware that the state space realization of a dynamical system is not unique. So if we have a dynamical system:

$\dot{x} = Ax + Bu$

$y = Cx$

Then we can write it as

$\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x}\\y
\end{bmatrix}
= G
\begin{bmatrix}x\\u\end{bmatrix}
$

where G is

$G = \begin{bmatrix}
A \ \ \ \ | & B\\ 
\hline
C \ \ \ \ | & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$

but one can also formulate it as

$G = \begin{bmatrix}
TAT^{-1} \ \ | & TB\\ 
\hline
CT^{-1} \ \  \ \ \ | & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

for any invertible matrix $T$.

I need to show that these two realizations of $G$ have the same Euclidean norm. I have found a video showing how similarity transformations preserve the trace and the determinant, but they did just an example problem, without doing the proof.

**Edit:**

It has been given that $G \in \mathcal{RH}_2$, where $\mathcal{RH}_2$ is a set of all real rational, strictly proper and stable transfer matrices. It is a Hilbert Space with the inner product:

$\langle F,G \rangle = \sup_{\sigma > 0} \left\{ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} trace \left\{ F^* (\sigma+j\omega) G(\sigma+j\omega) \right\} d\omega \right\}$

and the corresponding norm given by

${{\left\Vert F \right\Vert}_{2}}^2 = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} trace \left\{ 
F^*(j\omega)F(j\omega) \right\}d\omega$

Comment: Whatever it is that you're trying to prove, you will probably find it helpful to observe that
$$
G' = \left[ 
\begin{array}{c|c}
T&0\\
\hline 0&1
\end{array}
\right]G
\left[ 
\begin{array}{c|c}
T&0\\
\hline 0&1
\end{array}
\right]^{-1}
$$

Comment: Based on your edit, it seems as though the question is asking you to prove something that, as I showed, is not true. Could you check what the definition of $\mathcal{RH}_2$ is?

Comment: I just added the definition of $\mathcal{RH}_2$ in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is really the notation.

This is adding to the answer by obareey a bit more details. Given a linear system

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= A x + B u \\
y &= C x + D u \\
\end{align}
$$

In this question $D = 0$, but that doesn't really change anything. Then i.e. this is wrong:

$$
G = \left[  \begin{array}{c|c} A&B\\ \hline C&D \end{array} \right]
$$

As mentioned by obareey, $G$ is not a real matrix but instead a transfer function matrix. Often this is written instead like

$$
G(s) \sim \left[  \begin{array}{c|c} A&B\\ \hline C&D \end{array} \right]
$$

sometimes also written as

$$
G(s) \triangleq \left[  \begin{array}{c|c} A&B\\ \hline C&D \end{array} \right] \text{ or } G(s) \overset{s}= \left[  \begin{array}{c|c} A&B\\ \hline C&D \end{array} \right]
$$

Unfortunatly the notation varies and I have seen all of these. Some authors even use an equal sign, which makes things really confusing (or: wrong). However they really all mean the same, namely that $G(s) = C(s I - A)^{-1} B + D$ and $I$ is an identity matrix.

The $2$-norm of a general MIMO transfer function is

$$
\Vert G(s) \Vert_2 = \Big( \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \text{trace} \big[ G(j \omega)^H G(j \omega) \big] d \omega \Big)^{1/2}
$$

so of course $\Vert G(s) \Vert_2 = \Vert \widetilde{G}(s) \Vert_2$ when $G(s) = \widetilde{G}(s)$, assuming that $A$ is stable so that the integral exists, i.e. $\Vert G(s) \Vert_2 < \infty$. So all you need to show is that

$$
C(s I - A)^{-1} B + D = \widetilde{C}(s I - \widetilde{A})^{-1} \widetilde{B} + \widetilde{D}
$$

using an invertible $T$ and

$$
\begin{align}
\widetilde{A} &= T A T^{-1} \\
\widetilde{B} &= T B \\
\widetilde{C} &= C T^{-1} \\
\widetilde{D} &= D
\end{align}
$$

This is standard realization theory. You can check that both transfer functions are the same:

$$
\begin{align}
\widetilde{G}(s) &= \widetilde{C}(s I - \widetilde{A})^{-1} \widetilde{B} + \widetilde{D} \\
&= C T^{-1}(s I - T A T^{-1})^{-1} T B + D \\
&= C \big(T^{-1}(s I - T A T^{-1})T\big)^{-1}B + D \\
&= C \big(T^{-1} s I T - T^{-1} T A T^{-1} T\big)^{-1}B + D \\
&= C(s I - A)^{-1} B + D \\
&= G(s)
\end{align}
$$

because $T^{-1} s I T = s(T^{-1} I T)  = s(T^{-1} T) = s I$ since $T^{-1} T = I$ and the fact that $(K_1 K_2 K_3)^{-1} = K_3^{-1} K_2^{-1} K_1^{-1}$ for some invertible matrices $K_1, K_2, K_3$.

So because $G(s) = \widetilde{G}(s)$ their $2$-norms are the same.

Comment: could you please explain how $C T^{-1}(s I - T A T^{-1})^{-1} T B + D = C \big(T^{-1}(s I - T A T^{-1})T\big)^{-1}B + D \\$. I am not sure how the T being multiplied by B can be taken inside the brackets. And thank you for your awesome answer

Comment: @lin_dude Yes, just define $K_1 = T$, $K_2 = s I - T A T^{-1}$ and $K_3 = T^{-1}$ and apply the formula for products of inverse matrices that I mentioned at the end of the post: $C K_1^{-1} K_2^{-1} K_3^{-1} B = C (K_3 K_2 K_1)^{-1}B$.

Comment: Forgive my inexperience with linear algebra but how would $K_2 = sI - TAT^{-1}$ be an invertible matrix?

Comment: @lin_dude Because its determinant (which is the characteristic polynomial of $A$, or the denominator of $G(s)$, which both are also invariant to similarity transformations) $\det(s I - T A T^{-1}) = \det(s I - A)$ is zero only at the poles of $G(s)$, where $G(s)$ is not defined anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In this context $G$ is **not a matrix**, but a representation of the system. The 2-norm is not a matrix norm, but a **system norm**. This 2-norm is still defined by the system's frequency response. Since the transfer function matrix (hence the frequency response) of the system is invariant under similarity transformations, its 2-norm also does not change.

Answer (score -1):

It is **not** the case that the transformed matrix $G$ will have the same $2$-norm. For instance, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}, \quad B = \pmatrix{1\\0}, \quad C = \pmatrix{1&0}, \quad T = \pmatrix{2&0\\0&1}.
$$
We find that the matrices in question are
$$
G = \left[ 
\begin{array}{cc|c}
0&1&1\\
0&0&0\\
\hline
1&0&0
\end{array}
\right], \quad 
G' = \left[ 
\begin{array}{cc|c}
0&2&2\\
0&0&0\\
\hline
\frac 12&0&0
\end{array}
\right].
$$
Verify that these two matrices do not have the same $2$-norm.

---

For an example of a stable system for which this occurs, it suffices to replace $A$ with the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{-1&1\\0&-1}
$$
in the above example.

Comment: Yes, the 2-norm of $G'$ would be 2 times the 2-norm of G. I might be missing something then. I will edit my question and include the problem statement as well.

Comment: @pip_pydude Could it be the case that $T$ is necessarily an orthogonal matrix in this context?

Comment: Yes, that assumption can be made. How can we prove if that assumption is made.

Comment: I have added the problem statement to the question

Comment: @pip_pydude Ok! The fact that we're using the $2$-norm whose definition you added changes things a lot.

Comment: @pip To clarify: does $F^*$ refer to the conjugate-transpose of $F$?

Comment: @pip I'm a bit confused, actually. How would you define the "transfer matrix" of an input/state/output system? If we just want $Y = G(s) U$, then there would be no difference between the transfer matrix corresponding to a given state-space realization and the transfer matrix corresponding to the overall input/output system.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The transfer matrix is $G(s) = C(s I - A)^{-1} B + D$. The $I$ is identity matrix. Your example is invalid though, because your $A$ is not stable.

Comment: @SampleTime Stability doesn't make a difference; see my latest edit. Also, if $\|G\|_2$ is defined in terms of the transfer function $G$, then how does the phrase "$\|G\|_2$ is invariant to any state space realization of $G$" make sense? Apparently, the definition of $\|G\|_2$ has nothing to do with realizations.

Comment: @SampleTime I guess, per your answer, that that's the point. Different realizations correspond to the same transfer function, and therefore the "2-norm of the transfer function" is the same for each.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, I totally agree with you that the problem statement is strange: If the textbook did introduce realizations before, then it makes little sense to ask about the invariance of the 2-norm to different realizations, because by definition, the 2-norm is invariant to realizations (as it is defined in terms of the transfer function). If the textbook *did not* introduce realizations before, it is IMO a strange way to introduce them via the 2-norm...